# Python Binance API connection timeout

Tags: python, binance

Created a simple program with Binance API .

```
    from binance.client import Client
from time import sleep

API_KEY = "---"
API_SECRET = "---"
client = Client(API_KEY,API_SECRET)
def hist_data():
    global client
    while True:
        try:
            candle = client.get_historical_klines('BTCUSDT', '5m', '15m ago UTC')

            print(candle)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)         
            sleep(10)
hist_data()
```

I am getting three types of error

1. `raise ConnectionError(err, request=request) requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionAbortedError(103, 'Software caused connection abort'))`

I have fixed it by

```
 except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        sleep(10)
        pass
```

2. Second error is:

   ReadTimeout: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='...', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=10)

I have tried to fix it by set new client connection :

```
except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        sleep(10)                    
        client = Client(api,sec)
        pass # or continue
```

Here sleep time not matter.

3. When network connection not available after sleep() time getting error:

   ```
   **
   ```

   raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
   requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.binance.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/v3/ping (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x78947eb9a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 7] No address associated with hostname'))

**

Please help to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You're receiving connection errors due to your code containing a `while True` loop that continuously calls the Klines endpoint without adhering to the limits outlined in the official [Binance Spot Trading API documentation](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/rest-api.md#limits). Please consult the documentation and use `GET /api/v3/exchangeInfo` to obtain the current REST API limits in terms of allowable requests per IP.

Alternatively, you can use [WebSocket Stream](https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md#klinecandlestick-streams) (instead of REST API) to get live Klines updates without been limited by the requests per IP condition.

If helpful, there's also a Binance python connector which you can easily integrate into your code:

- [REST API Kline example](https://github.com/binance/binance-connector-python/blob/master/examples/spot/market/klines.py)
- [WebSocket Stream example](https://github.com/binance/binance-connector-python/blob/master/examples/websocket/spot/websocket_stream/symbol_kline.py)